# what are the ways to create a file descriptor?

Tags: c++, linux, epoll, qnx

The Wikipedia page for [`File Descriptor`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) lists the following system calls:

```
 - open(), open64()
 - creat(), creat64()
 - socket()
 - accept()
 - socketpair()
 - epoll_create() (Linux only)
 - pipe()
 - signalfd() (Linux only)
 - eventfd() (Linux only)
```

Are there any other methods on other platforms, especially on `QNX`?

I have a thread which is monitoring a bunch of sockets with a `poll()` call and receiving "Commands" from the sockets. Now I need to add the possibility to send such "Commands" from other threads running in the same process. I would like to avoid the overhead of writing into a pipe/socket within the same process if possible.

Can anyone think of somehow monitoring a conditional variable using `poll()` for example?

Comment: Does the "command" _have_ to be sent through a file descriptor? Why not simply have a message queue, and when the `poll` call time out you check this queue? And if you will "send" these commands in the same process as you do the receiving, why bother sending at all?

Comment: Linux has also `timerfd_create` to create a file descriptor....

Comment: And I believe a pipe to self is really quick.